# Help with integral with $\arcsin x$.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{(1+x^2)\arcsin x}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
I saw that $$(\arcsin x)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
and I tried to solve it "by parts"

Comment: And what happened when you tried to solve it by parts?

Comment: i met integral 1/sin^2x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
I = \int \frac{x dx}{\sin^2 x}
$$

$$
u = x, v = \int \frac{dx}{\sin^2 x}
$$

$$
I = uv - \int vdu
$$

$$
v = -\,\mathrm{ctg}\,x
$$

$$
I = -x\,\mathrm{ctg}\,x + \int \mathrm{ctg}\,x dx
$$

$$
\int \mathrm{ctg}\,x dx = \ln |\sin x| + C
$$

Comment: Late comment: whats ctg? I thought it could stand for cotangent?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Try $x = \sin u, dx = \cos u du$ to get
$$
\int \frac{(1+x^2)\arcsin x}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
 = \int \frac{(1+\sin^2 u) u \cos u du}{\sin^2 u\sqrt{1-\sin^2 u}}
 = \int \left(\csc^2 u + 1\right) u du
$$
which splits into 2 standard integrals.